# Setting an image as the title bar background

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I can't see an obvious solution to this.  I've been given an image file which includes both the "icon" and the text to be used in the title bar.

Ideally I'd like to simply turn the icon off, use the image in the title bar section, and be done with it.  I have a semi-solution:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
ShowIconOnTitleBar="False"    
    WindowTitleBrush="Black"
 >
<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Image Source="/StaticResources/Masthead.png"></Image>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
```

But it's not terribly effective.  There's now no drag and drop for half the title bar etc.  Is there an obviously better solution?  Should I just go back and use icon only and write the title myself?

Any cunning ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you play around with HitTestVisible? If the Background of your image is transparent you might be able to direct the click event on the image to th DragMove() method of your window. Or you could split the image and create two elements (icon and text) and simply redirect the click on the text to the DragMove()

Comment: You can use ImageBrush as Background for your title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better solution for your requirement. You should use the `TitleTemplate` instead the `LeftWindowCommands`.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="/StaticResources/Masthead.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.TitleTemplate>
```

Hope that helps.

But, by the way, why not using a simple image/icon (png) for the `Icon` property? And using the `Title` for the window title?

Comment: I agree, it would be the logical thing to do to just write the header myself, apparently that's not acceptable.  [Resistance is endlessly futile]